# How to make background-image all full-screen with html+css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a file html+css and I want to create background-image full-screen in HTML, and CSS I have set all properties for background image.
I want that background-image to fill all full-screen on devices and without scrolling on background-image so I try to do this:

```css
   * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .background-image {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        img {
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
     
    </div>
```

I set the background-image position relative and img position fixed to make fixed without scrolling but it brings the background-image is streched also text? Any idea to fixed it ?

Comment: You're stretching an actual image, not a background image.

Comment: j08691j08691 if we tray to make position absolute instead     position: fixed; background-image doesn't stretch but has effect of the scrolling, we don't want scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a background image use create a container and with css add the background-image property to the container: url('the path of my img')

Some advice I can give you is:

img

- Use IMG if you want people to print the page and you want the image to be included by default.
- Use IMG if you want the browser to display an image in proportion to the size of the text.
- Using IMG instead of background-image can drastically improve the performance of animations over a background.

css background-image

- Use CSS background-image if the image is not part of the content.
- Use CSS background-image when the image replaces the text
- Use CSS background-image combined with CSS background-size:cover in order to stretch a background image to cover the entire container
- Use CSS background-image if you want people to print the page and you do NOT want the image to be included by default.

Answer (score 0):

use the object-fit property and object-position property.
Here you are not actually working on the background. The image is a element not a background. To make it a background you have to use URL of the image.